# Returning the implemented type with rest in java

Tags: java, xml, rest, inheritance, jax-rs

I was wondering if is it possible to force the rest framework in java to return the actual implementation of some class instead of information that is only visible in the abstract class.

So I have a method that looks like

```
@GET
@Path("/}")
public Model getModel() {
    return (Car) system.getCar();
}
```

So I would like that when ever someones hits this path to what is returned is the information about the CAR and not just what is contained in the model. Is it possible to force this behavior with some annotations?

PS The example above is just for demonstration. The actually reason is that I have a class that has a parameter of the abstract class and I would like to see the information in the xml about the concrete implementation so that I know what type it is.

Thanks for assistance.

cheers

EDIT

To tell you truth I have no idea what is the implemenation. But maybe this artical about what I use can help you http://docs.codehaus.org/display/TYNAMO/tapestry-resteasy+guide

Comment: _Which_ JAX-RS-enabled framework is this? There are several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this in my REST project, it works without any extra work. I am using RestEasy framework to implement [REST](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) webservices. I checked this for XML as well as JSON datatype. For JSON serialization I am using [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library.

Comment: I want to create a more generic approach where I can return a Car or a Bus since the return type is their super type. However the fields that I wont to see in the xml is the Car or Bus fields not just the ones that are present in Model

Answer (score 0):

The REST implementation serializes an actual concrete instance of a class (not an abstract class, since you cant have an instance of an abstract class anyway) into the requested content type, for eg, JSON or XML.
What gets serialized is the domain object's fields based on their mappings.
You can control what fields of the domain object gets serialized, or you can create a custom POJO with only fields that you want to send in the response.

Comment: I know that what is returned is the concrete instance, however it only returns the fields that exist in the abstract class and not does that exist in the implementation

Answer (score 0):

It is not working on my JSON (with JACKSON), and I think it indeed **should not work**.
If your API provides a `Model` then it should not return `Car` fields. The executor of the API might not be able to parse the returned `Car` fields, since expected a `Model`.
This would be kind of up-casting which is generally shows a bad design. *IMHO*.
I liked the question though :)

Comment: Yea I know it shouldnt return that by default, but I am interested if there is some annotation that can force this behaviour. The way I see it since what I am returning is the actual xml/json I would expect that it sends info about everything that is not @Transient. cheers

Comment: This would be bad to the 'client', if you wannt to return A - return A, if you want to return B - return B, but you must declare what you return.